# Как удалить директорию без возможности восстановления?

Tags: файлы, golang

Как можно удалить файл, директорию при помощи Golang без возможности восстановления (permanently)?

Comment: Вам лучше пояснить, чем вас не устроил `os.RemoveAll`, иначе вопрос закроют как "непонятна суть".

Answer (score 0):

Мне в свое время помогал такой алгоритм:

1. Удаляем директорию.
2. Создаем в этом же месте директорию с таким же именем.
3. Удаляем эту новую директорию.

После этого все утилиты восстановления показывают только последнюю созданную (пустую и удаленную) директорию.

Ну а если по-честному надо уничтожать информацию, то надо использовать утилиту типа wipe, которая на низком уровне (то есть на уровне блоков) перезаписывает файлы мусором.

Comment: К сожалению это так не работает, драйвер файловой системы не запишет одни данные поверх других, а нормальная утилита найдёт обе копии файлов даже с одинаковым именем

Comment: @vnn198 Ну не знаю. Я пользовался этим методом довольно давно и тогда те утилиты восстановления удаленных файлов, которыми я потом смотрел диск, не видели первую копию. Может быть, конечно, с тех пор утилиты поумнели или файловая система стала более хитрая.

Comment: Утилита может не найти эту папку под её исходным именем, но если это не папка ,а файл то данные она найдёт, просто папка это тот-же файл но не имеющий данных, т.е. он только в MFT хранится и новая папка информацию об предыдущей удалит.

Comment: Тут проблема в том что при удалении файла его данные с диска не удаляются, а удаляется только запись об этом файле в MFT, и если просканировать весь HDD на предмет поиска типичных структур данных то многие файлы можно восстановить.

Answer (score 0):

Тут всё зависит от ОС, по сути есть много способов, простой выглядит так:
Открываем файл на запись, узнаём его длину и сначала записываем туда логические единички, затем ещё раз только нули, но тут есть такой момент что зачастую файловая система умная и не записывает новые данные поверх старых, а просто создаёт по сути новый файл меняя ссылку в MFT на него, поэтому лучше использовать другой метод, открыть файл на низком уровне узнав его физический адрес и перезаписав данные напрямую. Реализация второго метода сильно зависит от ОС и потребует запуска с правами администратора.

Comment: Спасибо, понял.. Права администратора присутствуют, а вот низкоуровневое программирование на Golang это конечно ещё та заморочка

Comment: Лучше записывать случайные данные, т.к. последовательная запись единичек и нулей не изменит общей картины, а лишь сделает её более блёклой. И в хорошей лаборатории файл можно будет восстановить.

Comment: Размер блоков в LBA - 512 килобайт. Если записывать по 128 байт и вызывать (*os.File).Sync(), то вряд ли файловая система найдёт более оптимальный выход, нежели просто перезаписать старые данные. Можно записывать по 128 через 384 для каждого блока и потом синхронизироваться, для оптимизации. А потом делать сдвиг на 128 и повторять, пока все 512 килобайт не будут перезаписаны. Да, файл должен быть открыт эксклюзивно. А лучше вообще использовать специальные утилиты типа shred.

Comment: Драйвер ФС как раз наоборот может записать данные в новое место, во первых для поддержки версионирования, а во вторых для избежания фрагментации, раньше драйвер ФС был глупый, а сейчас фоновая дефрагментация, снэпшоты и т.д.